# Is it possible to rearrange icons order in the action center of Windows 10 mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, action-center

On my Lumia 830 I configured my quick action icons in the action center.

Since finally Windows 10 Mobile can show more action icons in the action center, I tried to *rearrange the order* of the icons but I couldn't find a way.

Is it possible to rearrange the icons in the action center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As today, it's not possible to rearrange the icons in the action center but it seems it will be possible in the future as stated and shown in [this article](http://www.windowscentral.com/action-centers-quick-actions-get-drag-n-drop-customization-internal-builds):

> Screenshots of recent internal builds point to drag-n-drop
>   customization for quick actions, allowing you the ability to rearrange
>   the toggles as you see fit

[image]

These screenshots are taken from [Build 14322](http://www.windowscentral.com/action-center-and-cortana-improvements-part-windows-10-mobile-preview-build-14322).

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately you can't rearrange *all* the action icons, only the *quick action* ones - those which are always shown, whether the action icons are collapsed or expanded :

[image: Quick Action icons in the Action Center]

For changing or reordering the *Quick actions* :
 `Settings` -> `System` -> `Notifications & actions`

[image: Notifications & actions settings in WP10]